# Solving quadratic equation in $Z_{97}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I need help solving equations in finite field. Specifically i need to solve $3x^2 + 52 = c $ where $c = 11^{32n + 8}$ in $\mathbb Z_{97}$. I am assuming it has to use the fact that $c = 11^{32n + 8}\equiv 1\mod 96 $ which i proved in first part of the problem. How would i approach solving this problem?

Comment: I think the value of $x$ will differ with the value of $n$.

Comment: Good ol quadratic formula works.

Comment: @user236182 You are right it should be 1 instead of -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve for $x^2$ by first multiplying through by $65$:

$$x^2 = 65c+15$$

**Case I:** If $n=3k$ then by fermat $c=11^{32n+8} = (11^{96})^k\cdot 11^8 = 36$

Then we have $x^2 = 27 \implies x\in \{30, 67\}$

**Case II:** If $n=3k+1$ then $c=11^{32n+8} = (11^{96})^k\cdot 11^{40} = 62$

Then we have $x^2 = 68 \implies x\in \emptyset$

**Case III:** If $n=3k+2$ then $c=11^{32n+8} = (11^{96})^k\cdot 11^{72} = 96$ (or $-1$)

Then we have $x^2 = 47\implies x\in \{12, 85\}$

Comment: I just have to ask how did you for example $x^2 = 47$? Was it by tying different numbers or by some sort of algorithm.

Comment: $47^{(103-1)/2}=1$ so I know there are two solutions $s, (p-s)$. There are algorithms that do this, but I first try a couple things. I know that $s(p-s)=-47$. Now $s^2-97s-47$ won't factor easily, so add 97 until something looks vialble. The first couple aren't worth checking. The hope is that we won't have to look very long. Checking D=$\dfrac{k\cdot (97-k)}{-47+97(k-1)}$ starting with maybe $k=4,5$ in $<10$ tries, you'll get to $D=1$ ($k=12$). So $(s-12)(s-85)=0$. etc